# MATLAB: Sum of an infinite series, with Fibonacci coefficients

Tags: matlab, fibonacci

I need to find f(x), which the sum of the following infinite series:

f(x) = sum {C_{n}*x^{n}} ; sum goes from n = 0 to Inf

C[n] is the modified Fibonacci series such that, C[0] = 2, C[1] = 3, and C[n] = C[n-1] + C[n-2].

for such f(x), it converges to natural numbers for x in [0,1)
I need to find these natural numbers. How to go about it?

I initially tried it by first defining a vector C of length 1000, and then tried symsum for the series, MATLAB threw the following error:
Function 'subsindex' is not implemented for MuPAD symbolic objects.

Then I defined a symbolic f, in terns of C[n] and x using 'for' loop. 
And then ran a loop over x to discover the natural numbers.

The challenge with this approach is that, it depends on the number of terms, and the precision I choose. Also,.. this gets very demanding.

Comment: If you mean real numbers instead - learning about the closed form of the Fibonacci series will make it easy. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Comment: f(x) converges to a natural number, for x in [0,1).
Example, for x = .5, f(x) = 10.

Comment: @user2006190 tried it numerically, for x=0.5 it converged to 10, but for other values - not so much. See [here](http://ideone.com/YA6jaY).